# How to transition an item to move to the left on hover

Tags: html, css

I would like my element (which i have named as a class benefits-button) to slide in from the left upon hover.  I have created the following two sets of css rules but I am having no luck:

```
.benefit-buttons {
     transition-property: color, left;
     transition-duration: 200ms;
     transition-delay: .1s;
     transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.benefit-buttons:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    color: #FF0000;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you mean instead of putting 'left', i should try 'left-margin' in the transition property?

Comment: See my answer. For better help, describe the desired behavior in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element cannot have a left property unless it's absolutely-positioned ([read more](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)).  Try a left margin as an alternative:

```
.benefit-buttons {
    width: 25%;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    transition-delay: .1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.benefit-buttons:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    color: #FF0000;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kmdsdgzz/)**

Comment: The button was sliding out from under my mouse when it was smaller, creating a partial animation. The movement should be substantially less than the element width for a good user experience.

Answer (score 4):

```css
.benefit-buttons {
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     background:red;
}
.benefit-buttons:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    color: #FF0000;
    transform:translate(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="benefit-buttons"></div>
```